# Warn about password expiration without forcing change

Tags: password, pam, accounts

It's pretty simple.  I would like to figure out what combination of changes in `/etc/login.defs` and/or `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac`. I would need to perform to allow the following behavior:

- I want a user's password to be valid for 60 days.
- After 60 days, the system needs to yell at the user when they log in, telling them they need to change their password ASAP.
- The system must not impede the user's access to the system.
- This must apply to existing users (non-system accounts, `UID >=500`) as well as any newly-created users.

Rationale:  Limited users will not be managing the system account passwords, only system admin(s).  Therefore, users should not have their access to the system impeded because the admin missed a password change.  The number of accounts is rather small (maybe 9 or 10), but we're all human and we forget to do stuff from time to time.

I'm not sure if `login.defs` or `PAM` offer this.  The documentation leads me to believe that you can either have the system force the user to change their password when it expires, or you can have the password not age at all.  A third option is to have the password age limit set to some huge amount, like 9,999 days, and then start warning the user that their password will expire in 9,936 days, but that's not really what I need either.  I've done other kinds of `PAM` configuration, so it's not my first trip around the block.  I'm just stuck on this problem.

So, can this be done with `PAM`/`login.defs`, or do I need another utility that can take their place?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not averse to using a custom script, try this as a [`pam_exec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pam_exec.8.html) script:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
LAST_DATE=$(date -d "$(chage -l $PAM_USER  | awk -F: '/Last password/{print $2}')" '+%s')
TODAY=$(date '+%s')
MAX_AGE=60
if (( (($TODAY - $LAST_DATE) / 86400) > $MAX_AGE ))
then
    echo "Please change your password!"
fi
```

Save it somewhere (say, `/usr/local/bin/pass-warn.sh`), and add a line to `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
session optional pam_exec.so stdout /usr/local/bin/pass-warn.sh
```

Comment: Having some trouble with the comment formatting, so I ask to be excused in advance.  
If I use PAM_USER at the command line for testing, chage outputs a help section, but I do get results with USER.  
Regardless of which I use in the script, I get the following error after SSHing in:  
`stdout failed: exit code 2`  
I'm still debugging, but any insights would be helpful.  Also, could this work as-is for console (non-SSH) logins with the CLI and GUI if I drop the pam_exec.so line into /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac?

Comment: @the_non-guru_guru that is odd. Can you look up `man pam_exec` on your system to see how it differs from [Ubuntu's](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/pam_exec.8.html)? And I think it should for CLI (but not for GUI, where would the output go to?), but I don't have a local system to check it on. Let me see if I can get a VM running.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm working on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5 system.  If you have (or want to download) a CentOS 6.5 installer, they are practically the same OS.  I'll take a peek and see if I can find Ubuntu's manpage so I can do a side-by-side.

Comment: @the_non-guru_guru I have linked to Ubuntu's man page in the previous comment, and I have a CentOS 6.5 server on which I can test this out. Will update if I can fix this.

Comment: @@muru I missed that, my bad.  The CentOS flavor lacks the stdout argument.  Setting log=/dev/stdout gives me more info.  `/usr/local/bin/pass-warn.sh failed: exit code 2`

Comment: @the_non-guru_guru Doesn't look like it can be fixed (see http://serverfault.com/questions/566622/pam-exec-stdout-issue), so perhaps Bratchley's `profile.d` way is what you need to use.

Comment: @@muru I'm sorry, I didn't see your comment because it was hidden.  It's a shame that it can't be done this way, because it seems like the "right" way to do it.  I will give Bratchley's method a try.  I've used global login scripts before to make environment changes before user-level login scripts kick in, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you set password aging at all then `pam_unix.so` is going to deny their authentication after the password expires. To do what you're wanting you can probably add something to their login scripts. For example, I can add the following to `/etc/profile.d`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
maxDays=30
dayLastChanged=$(passwd -S $(whoami) | awk '{print $3}')

currentTimestamp=$(date "+%s")
lastChangeTimestamp=$(date -d $dayLastChanged "+%s")

timestampDifference=$(( $currentTimestamp - $lastChangeTimestamp ))
maxSeconds=$(( $maxDays * 86400 ))

if [[ $timestampDifference -gt $maxSeconds ]]; then    
   echo "Yo, you need to change your password bud. Otherwise the guys with white-on-white ties are coming for you."    
fi
```

Comment: Files in `profile.d` are sourced, IIRC, so the shebang line isn't very useful.

Comment: It's just something I always do for all my scripts. I just decided at some point in the past that I needed to get in the habit of always specifying my interpreter with the idea that it'll be ignored if it doesn't matter.

Comment: The danger with this habit is that if the file is sourced, it may be in a shell that's incompatible with your shebang. For example, here, you used a bash-specific construct (double brackets), but scripts under `/etc/profile.d` can be included by any Bourne-style shell, some of which will choke on `[[`. You might as well use the portable form `[ … ]` here since you aren't making any use of bash-specific functionality.

Comment: @Gilles. If that did happen then it was going to choke no matter what I did. Adding the shebang didn't hurt anything. That's more of an argument for writing sh-compatible scripts. The double square brackets _were_ a mistake, however. The script still functions, just written in an unnecessary way.

Comment: @Bratchley This appears to work for the root account and fails for non-root users with "Only root can do that".  A combination of your solution and muru's works. I basically use his script in the directory you specified.  The only time it chokes is when you log in as an account that is not local to the system, but managed externally. Limited users appear to be able to run chage, but not passwd -S (at least on my system here).